# Computing sample statistics using NumPy functions with a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to create a function that returns either the mean, median, or standard deviation of all columns in a Pandas DataFrame using NumPy functions.

It is for a school assignment, so there's no reason for using NumPy other than it is what is being asked of me.  I am struggling to figure out how to use a NumPy function with a Pandas DataFrame for this problem.

**Here is the text of the problem.**

The code cell below contains a function called comp_sample_stat that accepts 2 parameters "df" which contains data from the dow jones for a particular company, and stat which will contain 1 of the 3 strings: "mean", "std", or "median".

For this problem:

- if the stat is equal to "mean" return the mean of the dataframe columns using numpy's mean function
- if the stat is equal to "median" return the median of the dataframe columns using numpy's median function
- if the stat is equal to "std" return the std of the dataframe columns using numpy's std function

**Here is the function I have written.**

```
def comp_sample_stat(df, stat='mean'):
'''
Computes a sample statistic for any dataframe passed in

Parameters
----------
df: Pandas dataframe 

Returns
-------
a pandas dataframe
'''
    df_mean = df.apply(np.mean(df))
    df_median = df.apply(np.median(df))
    df_std = df.apply(np.std(df))

    if stat is str('std'):
        return df_std
    elif stat is str('median'):
        return df_median
    else:
        return df_mean
```

**df is a DataFrame that has been defined previously in my assignment as follows:**

```
def read_data(file_path):
'''
Reads in a dataset using pandas.

Parameters
----------
file_path : string containing path to a file

Returns
-------
pandas dataframe with data read in from the file path
'''
    read_file = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(read_file)
    return new_df    

df = read_data('data/dow_jones_index.data')
```

**The variable df_AA has also been previously defined as follows:**

```
def select_stock(df, symbol):
'''
Selects data only containing a particular stock symbol.

Parameters
----------
df: dataframe containing data from the dow jones index
stock: string containing the stock symbol to select

Returns
-------
dataframe containing a particular stock
'''
    stock = df[df.stock == symbol]
    return stock
df_AA = select_stock(df.copy(), 'AA')
```

**When I call the function within a Jupyter Notebook as follows:**

```
comp_sample_stat(df_AA)
```

**I get the following error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-17-a2bcbeedcc56> in <module>()
 22         return df_mean
 23 
---> 24 comp_sample_stat(df_AA)

<ipython-input-17-a2bcbeedcc56> in comp_sample_stat(df, stat)
 11     a pandas dataframe
 12     '''
---> 13     df_mean = df.apply(np.mean(df))
 14     df_median = df.apply(np.median(df))
 15     df_std = df.apply(np.std(df))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, 
**kwds)
6012                          args=args,
6013                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6014         return op.get_result()
6015 
6016     def applymap(self, func):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in 
get_result(self)
316                                       *self.args, **self.kwds)
317 
--> 318         return super(FrameRowApply, self).get_result()
319 
320     def apply_broadcast(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in 
get_result(self)
140             return self.apply_raw()
141 
--> 142         return self.apply_standard()
143 
144     def apply_empty_result(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in 
apply_standard(self)
246 
247         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
249 
250         # wrap results

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in 
apply_series_generator(self)
275             try:
276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
278                     keys.append(v.name)
279             except Exception as e:

TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 
quarter')
```

Comment: Can you post more of the error message?

Comment: Sure, I can post the whole thing, but it is pretty long.

Comment: It would just be helpful to see where the error happened - if you can, isolate the part that identifies which part of your functions tripped the error.

Comment: Ok, I posted it.  Let me know if you need me to format it better or anything like that.

Comment: It appears to be getting tripped by the definition of the variable df_mean, but then it is giving several other functions that are having issues with that variable declaration and I don't know what any of those are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataFrame.apply` expects you to pass it a function, not a dataframe. So you should be passing `np.mean` without arguments.

That is, you should be doing something like this:

```
df_mean = df.apply(np.mean)
```

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).